# An idiom for "saddened /or fretful" due to the weather

Tags: idioms, vocabulary, idiom-requests

I have been searching for an idiom for saddened for quite a while now, and am not found an answer that satisfied me.

I have found the idioms below

> • down in the dumps-  Someone who is down in the dumps is depressed or feeling gloomy.
>
> • down in the mouth-  When someone is down in the mouth, they look unhappy, discouraged or depressed.
>
> • face like a wet week-end

however, those didn't suit my needs as the emotion it was expressing was a bit too strong for me, as I was simply describing a scene where the dreary weather influenced my mood (sort of like saddened).

I am thinking if there's any idioms or phases or just words which describes my situation. Thankyou !

Comment: Having the sads (SADS — seasonal affective disorder syndrome). That’s what many people say in my area in the depths of winter.

Comment: How about "out of sorts".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common idiom is *rainy day blues*. It's hard to find a dictionary entry, but there are plenty of uses on the internet, including [this one](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/weather/9381397/Drowning-in-rainy-day-blues.html) from a British newspaper.

It's generally understood to be caused by the weather, temporary, not too serious and with a strong element of boredom - just what you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean "… due to the weather" then the usual expression would be "under the weather".

How does that not suit your search, please?

Answer (score 0):

The "winter blahs" or "rainy day blahs" describe this exact feeling. Not abject depression but simply the blahs.